# jQuery Nestable wrong serialize

Tags: jquery, json, serialize

Использую плагин `http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/` Структуру храню в сериализованном виде

```
[{"id":1}]
```

Для построения использую данный код `http://jsfiddle.net/53WSc/9/`

Проблема в том что после построения криво работает сериализация, т.е. к примеру вместо

```
[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3}
```

и т.д. получаю

```
[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},
```

т.е. "id":1 куда то исчезает, если еще что либо изменить, исчезает "id":2 и так пока не останется пустой массив.

Саму сериализацию делаю так

```
$('.dd').nestable().on('change', function(e) {
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target);
    console.log(JSON.stringify($('.dd').nestable('serialize')));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Сильно глубоко не вникал в *nestable*, но заметил следующее:

1. Библиотека в качестве списков воспринимает только `<ol>` (если иное не указано при создании экземпляра). Поскольку ваш верхний уровень это `<ul>`, *nestable* его не учитывает при сериализации; Соответсвенно я поменял `<ul class="dd-list"></ul>` на `<ol class="dd-list"></ol>` и `$('#nestable ul').append(buildItem(item));` на `$('#nestable > ol').append(buildItem(item));` и сериализация стала работать исправно;
2. В библиотеке для адресации элементов внутри списка требуется указание класса для корневого элемента `<div id="nestable">`. Поскольку он не был указан, перетаскивание элементов не работало.

Рабочий вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/53WSc/13/